# Dynamic converter parameter on DataGrid

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-5.0

I have a DataGrid where some columns display double values. I use a converter to format this values because it needs some calculations. 
The format is like:
If the value is 1,200 it shows 1,2K
If the value is 1,200,000 it shows 1,2M
If the value is 1,200,000,000 it shows 1,2B

There is a checkbox with the option to enable/disable the format, so I need to pass the status of the checkbox as a parameter to the converter.

I was trying to bind the ConverterParameter, but it is not possible in Silverlight 5.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using Silverlight 5 and MVVM (without any framework like Prism or MVVMLight).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

1. Have simple visibility converters to control visibility i.e. visibleifFormatIsRegular , visibleifFormatIsNotRegular
2. two value converters to convert the value in each of the formats you need your value to be shown
3. Two textblocks with the format mentioned below only the converter names change

   textblock 1 ==> Text={Binding propertyvalue, Converter{staticresource YourIvalueConverterforactualFormatConversion}} Visibility={Binding checkboxtoggledProperty, converter {visibilityConverter }}

Hope this helps!